# Why am I getting three outputs when I have a space in batch variable?

Tags: batch-file, filesystems

The code is intended to be a simple symbolic link creator for the test.tx file, but when I run it I get three outputs:

```
mklink "H:\Backups\Batch Files\Batch" "H:\Backups\Batch Files\File System\test.txt"
mklink "H:\Backups\Batch Files\File" "H:\Backups\Batch Files\File System\test.txt"
mklink "H:\Backups\Batch Files\test.txt" "H:\Backups\Batch Files\File System\test.txt"
```

Script:

```
@Echo off

set "src=H:\Backups\Batch Files\File System\test.txt"
set "des=H:\Backups\Batch Files"

FOR %%A IN (%src%) DO (echo mklink "%des%\%%~nxA" "%src%")

timeout 30
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the value assign to `src` is `H:\Backups\Batch Files\File System\test.txt`.

This is three separate space-separated strings, hence `for` will `do` the `echo` three times, once with each string.

If you want `cmd` to interpret the string as a single entity, you can

1/ Quote the string when assigned, `set "src="H:\Backups\Batch Files\File System\test.txt""`
or
2/ Quote the value when used `FOR %%A IN ("%src%") DO (...`

Comment: Ahhh! "Separate space-separated-strings" - brilliant! I didn't realize that. I've had this problem in other scripts too. Thanks for your help!